# nodeJS - Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I get this error every time I launch `npm start`, from what I've read, it's due to a process running on the same port, so I have to search it with `netstat -nlp | grep 3000` and kill the process.

But it's quite inconvenient to do this on every file change, I also have an error with nodemon which may cause it : `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

[image]

App.js :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
mongoose.Promise = require("bluebird");
var apiRouter = require('./routes/routes');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//raccourci pour bootstrap
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//Ajout du slug course
app.use('/courses', apiRouter);

//Connexion à la bdd
mongoose.connect('mongodb://my_connection_string')
                .then(
                    console.log("CONNECTE !!!")
                );

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Bonjour !");
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code? (app.js file)

Comment: Done it @Héctor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill mongoose when your app crashes:

```
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
    mongoose.connection.close(() => {
        console.log("App is closing, ending mongoose connection");
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

Although, you may be experiencing this bug:

[`remy/nodemon #1025`: Nodemon frequently leaves the child process running (detached)](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1025)

Comment: oh mate, I had this problem so many times, thank you for pointing it out!